# Backing up Initial and Running configurations for Nortel Baystack 325-24G

Tags: backup, router, switch, tftp, nortel

I recently came across a Nortel Baystack 325-24G switch. This is the first time I've come across a Nortel device of any sort, so I am a little intimidated. My problem is that I have been trying to get the startup and running configurations via both the CLI and the Menus but its become quite apparent that it isn't like the Cisco Switches/Routers. I've searched online but have only found Configuration Guides by Avaya.

Also I'd like to know - is there a way to take backups regularly (something like tftp)?

Pardon me but I'm a n00b when it comes to routers and switches.

Thanks in advance..

EDIT: Still havent found a way to get the running config via the CLI

Comment: Check out 'rancid' at http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/, I use it with HP's and Ciscos.

Comment: rancid works for these switches.

Comment: Thanks @3molo .. I'll look up rancid and let you know how it goes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out 'rancid' at shrubbery.net/rancid, I use it with HP's and Ciscos.